# Agents get blocked in the seize

Tags: anylogic

Agents get stucked in the seize (purple circle in the image)  even though the resource is not busy.
As shown in the image the agent Pazienti_ps[213] is stucked in the seize block. The resources he is asking are not busy at all. (Features of the resources asked are shown in the right side of the image, orange arrow)
Furthermore the agent is not even present in the queue of the resources.
Resources capacity is directly set by a schedule, 8-18 are all of capacity 2, 18-8 are all of 1 element capacity.
I've tought that the problem could be the schedule, but I don't know how to handle the problem.
Any suggestion?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiTzP.png

Comment: The only way to solve such complicated flows and models: strip it back until the problem disappears (or change setup). Then you know the root cause and can fix it or ask about it. We cannot do this for you and there is nothing obvious here that could be the root cause. Rest assured though: the blocks work as designed, it is very unlikely you found a bug. For the future: build models differently: start simple, test. Add a tiny change: test. Repeat and you will never wonder again "why is this not working"... Because you only did a tiny change and know the answer :)

Comment: the typical reason for this is that you are using custom resource choice and you are not using recalculate resource choice condition function